# c# can't use image in resources in the code?

Tags: c#, image, resources

I want to use images in my applcation .

I have added 4 images like this :
WindowsAplication1-Resources-Images-add Existing file (select my images ) 
I can see then in the window , and also  see them in the solution Explorer - resources.

but when I use this command to use the image

```
pictureBox2.Image = Prooerties.Resources.**** (I don't see the images)
```

why is it?

what did I do wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this will be help you

```
pictureBox2.Image = global::(SolutionName).Properties.Resources.(ImageName);
```

Make sure change (SolutionName) and (ImageName) as yours

Answer (score 0):

```
pictureBox2.Image = global::(namespace).Resources.****
```

Check "Project - Properties - Resources.resx - Resources.Designer.cs" in namespace

There will be "class Resources" in it.